# Error showing traffic data with bingmaps 8

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

I'm programatically generating HTML to show bing maps. The following generated HTML correctly marks the address, but the showTraffic() part seems to have no effect. For the sake of privacy, I've altered the address, omitted the bing-maps credentials, and truncated the end (which I've established is working) but otherwise this is the actual html generated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<title>Job Site--Map</title> 
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var map, searchManager,trafficManager; 
function GetMap() { 
    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map("#myMap", { 
        credentials: "*** VALID CREDENTIALS OMITTED HERE ***" 
    });         
    geocodeQuery("1000 Dairy Ashford, Houston, TX 77077");      
    showTraffic();      
}
function showTraffic() {
    if (!trafficManager) { 
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.Traffic", function () { 
            trafficManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Traffic.TrafficManager(map);  
        }); 
    }
    trafficManager.show();
}   
function geocodeQuery(query) { 
    if (!searchManager) { 
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.Search", function () { 
            searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(map); 
            geocodeQuery(query); 
        }); 
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the traffic module is loaded asynchronous, but your code is synchronous, thus the trafficManager is null when you call the show function. Here is a modified version of this function for you.

```
function showTraffic() {
    if (!trafficManager) { 
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.Traffic", function () { 
            trafficManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Traffic.TrafficManager(map); 
            trafficManager.show(); 
        }); 
    }else{
        trafficManager.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is every bing maps call always async? Or is it just the way this call is made? (Sorry, both javascript and bing maps are outside my expertise, so I'm trying to fill gaps.)

Comment: When you load a module, it is async as it has to download the code for that module. If it did this synchronously it could potentially freeze your browser until the code was downloaded which would make for a poor experience.